# Cannot access 'person' before initialization Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm getting a "Cannot access 'person' before initialization" Error. I don't have const person anywhere else except this file. I'm new to js so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: I fix that error but now I'm getting a different error message. "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: getMember is not defined".

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
const love = Math.random() * 100;
const loveIndex = Math.floor(love / 10);
const loveLevel = "".repeat(loveIndex) + "".repeat(10 - loveIndex);

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#ffb6c1")
    .addField(`☁ **${person.displayName}** loves **${message.member.displayName}** this much:`,
    ` ${Math.floor(love)}%\n\n${loveLevel}`);

    let person = getMember(message, args[0]);

 if (!person || message.author.id === person.id) {
    person = message.guild.members
        .filter(m => m.id !== message.author.id)
        .random();

message.channel.send(embed);

}}

module.exports.config = {
name: "love",
description: "Calculates the love affinity you have for another person.",
usage: "[mention | id | username]",
accessableby: "Members",
aliases: ["affinity"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```js
    .addField(`☁ **${person.displayName}** loves **${message.member.displayName}** this much:`,
```

`person` is not defined.

Try moving the block where you initialize `person` up above the `const embed = ...` statement.

Comment: I did that, and i now I got a different error message. "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: getMember is not defined"

Comment: @Mari getMember is not a defined method in your code. Where do you expect it to be? Are you wanting `message.member`?

Answer (score 0):

That error is usually caused by trying the make a reference to a class before the code for the class itself is initialized. Try declaring person after class definition.

Comment: I did that, and i now I got a different error message. "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: getMember is not defined" .